# Estimating functions run time

Tags: r, runtime, time-series, cluster-analysis

I have a large list of 15000 elements each containing 10 numbers (`data`)
I am doing a time series cluster analysis using

```
distmatrix <- dist(data, method = "DTW")
```

This has now been running for 24 hours. Is it likely to complete any time soon. Is there a way of checking on it's progress. I don't want to abort just in case it's about to finish.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, but what I can advise you is that your R script should ideally generate some kind of logging output as it is crunching data.  For example, it could write to a log after every N elements gets processed, which would give you some idea of where your progress stands.

Comment: How can I log if dist is a library function which is a black box as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Good point, you can't.  One other option would be for you to benchmark the `dist()` function on smaller chunks of data, so that you know roughly how long it takes per size of input.  Then you could extrapolate the running time to the actual size of your data set.

Comment: Ok I can see that. So I will have to terminate my current run.I had been a way of avoiding that

Comment: Why not just test your process on another machine and extrapolate a ball park for how long your process will run? If  your process is truly processor limited then hand coding an analog to `dist(..., method='DTW')` that can be parallelized might be your only option (assuming you're running an architecture with multiple cores).

Comment: `Error in dist(data, method = "DTW") : invalid distance method`